# Need help passing arrays elements/info to functions C++

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I am having some trouble using/writing functions.

right now I am working on a problem trying to validate a user provided password.

The requirements are:

1 upper case letter
1 lower case letter
1 number
at least 6 characters

each requirment is meant to be validate by passing from main() to a function.

I wrote a function for the lower case letter and I keep getting error messages saying there is an unresolved external error. However, when I pass the user_password from the main to the length function it returns the proper statement.

This is the error I keep getting in Visual Studio:

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl lowercase(char * const)" (?lowercase@@YA_NQAD@Z) referenced in function _main

Error   4   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Here is the code I have written so far

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool length(char[]);
bool lowercase(char[]);


int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 20;
    char user_password[SIZE];
    cout << "Please enter a password" << endl;
    cout << "**********************************************" << endl;
    cout << "Must contain at least 1 upper case letter" << endl;
    cout << "Must contain at least 1 lower case letter" << endl;
    cout << "Must contain at least 1 number" << endl;
    cout << "**********************************************" << endl;
    cin.getline(user_password, SIZE);

    length(user_password);

    lowercase(user_password);

    return 0;
}
bool length(char password1[])
{

    int length;
    length = strlen(password1);

    if (length < 6)
    {
        cout << "Password needs at least 6 characters" << endl;
    }
    else if (length < 6)
    {
        cout << "Character requirements met" << endl;
    }

    return password1;
}
bool lowercase(char password2)
{
    if (!islower(password2))
    {
        cout << "Password requires at least 1 lower letter" << endl;
    }
    else if (islower(password2))
    {
        cout << "Lower case letter requirement met" << endl;
    }

    return password2;
}
```

Comment: use std::vector or std::array instead of raw arrays

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of character arrays for strings and your problem passing strings as arrays goes away.

Comment: Look at how you declare the function `lowercase()` at the top and how it is different from how you define the same function at the bottom. They should have the same type of parameters but they are different.

Comment: Both the ifs in your length statement are the same

Answer (score 2):

This is because the signature on the function definition doesn't match the signature on the declaration.

```
bool lowercase(char[]);

bool lowercase(char password2)  // OOPS! Doesn't match.
{
    ....
}
```

should be

```
bool lowercase(char password2[])
{
    ....
}
```

You should really use either `std::string` or at the very least pass by `const char` pointer. Passing by `const` pointer is more identifiable with passing a pointer to a null terminated string.

```
bool lowercase(const char* password2)
```

Either way you will also need to change how you are calling `islower` since it accepts a character value instead of a pointer to a string. To to this you will need to iterate over the string in `for` or `while` loop and check each character individually. You're trying to return a pointer as a boolean value, this won't work. Something like this will:

```
bool lowercase(char password2[])
{

    for (const char*ptr = password2; *ptr; ++ptr)
    {
        if (!islower(*ptr))
        {
            cout << "Password requires at least 1 lower letter" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    cout << "Lower case letter requirement met" << endl;
    return true;
}
```

As noted in the comments your implementation of `length` is also bonkers. not only are you checking for the same length twice but you're trying to return a pointer as a boolean value.

```
bool lowercase(char password2[])
{
    unsigned int notlower = 0;
    for (const char*ptr = password2; *ptr; ++ptr)
    {
        if (!islower(*ptr))
        {
            notlower++;
        }
    }

    if (notlower == strlen(password2))
    {
        cout << "Password requires at least 1 lower letter" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    cout << "Lower case letter requirement met" << endl;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: tried your suggestion. Received the following errorsWarning    1 warning C4800: 'char []' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)Error                             2 error C2664: 'int islower(int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char []' to 'int' 
5 IntelliSense: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int"

Comment: @TPC4589 Even though it's outside the scope of the actual question in your post, I've included an update that points out other problems with your code and example solutions.

Comment: we haven't learned std::string yet, so I am not sure how to use it, but I will look into it

Comment: @TPC4589 - `we haven't learned std::string yet`  But you are using it, at least indirectly.  Your original post has `#include <string>` which is the only place where `std::string` exists.  None of your other functions you used requires this header.